# ServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddScoped and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, windows-services, quartz.net, service-provider

I have a windows service which uses `Quartz` for scheduling the tasks. And I am trying to achieve the `Dependency Injection` as by default the `Quartz` doesn't support that with default `Job Factory`. So I had to create a custom `Job Factory` as follows.

```
var scheduler = await GetScheduler();
var serviceProvider = GetConfiguredServiceProvider();
scheduler.JobFactory = new CustomJobFactory(serviceProvider);
```

And below is my code for `GetConfiguredServiceProvider()`.

```
private IServiceProvider GetConfiguredServiceProvider() {
    var services = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddScoped<IDailyJob, DailyJob>()
    .AddScoped<IWeeklyJob, WeeklyJob>()
    .AddScoped<IMonthlyJob, MonthlyJob>()
    .AddScoped<IHelperService, HelperService>();
    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

But on the line `.AddScoped<IDailyJob, DailyJob>()` I am getting an error as

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'ServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddScoped' and no accessible extension method 'AddScoped' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'ServiceCollection' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Anyone else faced this same issue?

Comment: hmmm, well, *are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?*

Comment: I feel like there should be a duplicate but I couldn't find one, so +1 (although a trivial fix)

Comment: Yes, I also thought initially, then I could not find one. That is why I posted it. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure out the issue. The problem was that I was missing a reference for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`. Usually this will be added to your packages when you install the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package, it seems like somehow it didn't automatically added to my solution. And after I add the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` the build error was gone.

You can also try removing the package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and then reinstall the same and check whether it is adding the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` by default.

[image]

Hope it helps.