# 'ServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddStrawberryShakeClient'

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, strawberry-graphql, strawberryshake

Using a console application, I want to download data from a GraphQL API on my local machine.

I have added the following NuGet packages to my project in Visual Studio:

- StrawberryShake (13.8.1)
- StrawberryShake.CodeGeneration.CSharp (12.22.2)
- StrawberryShake.Transport.Http (13.9.0)

I have also downloaded the schema file and stored it in a folder under the name `schema.graphql`.

I then added a client factory class with the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using StrawberryShake;


namespace GraphQLNamespace
{
    public class GraphQLClientFactory
    {
        public IServiceProvider CreateClient(string apiUrl)
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            // Configure the HTTP transport
            serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("GraphQLClient", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl));

            // Add StrawberryShake services
            serviceCollection.AddStrawberryShakeClient();

            return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
}
```

On the line `serviceCollection.AddStrawberryShakeClient();` I get the following error:

> Error CS1061  'ServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddStrawberryShakeClient' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddStrawberryShakeClient' accepting a first argument of type
> 'ServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly
> reference?)   MyGraphQLProject    C:\Users\MY_PROFILE_NAME\source\repos\GraphQLForTOBE\GraphQLClientFactory.cs

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: _"Is there anything I am missing?"_ - a `using` , pretty sure. The extension needs to be visible.

Comment: @Fildor You are right. I added the `using StrawberryShake;` but it made no difference. Same error.

Comment: According to docs (https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/v13/get-started/console), it uses code generation and name of extension method based on the name in the schema. Please check what name is used in schema and check generated C# code

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310998/servicecollection-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-addscoped-and-no-accessible) solution was to add `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` Nuget

Comment: @Renat that did not work. I downloaded the Abstractions package but it was not recognized in the `using` statement.